# Why does Donald Duck say this strange line on page three of Don Rosa's "The Dream of a Lifetime", part two (2002)?

Tags: comics, disney, donald-duck, scrooge-mcduck

On page three, panel four (first panel of second row), in the second part of *The Dream of a Lifetime*, English original, Donald shouts toward Bombie the Zombie, but addressing Scrooge:

> **HALP!** HE'S COMING FOR ME! HE'LL GET ME **AGAIN!**

Emphasis as it appears in the comic.

Absolute page number in *The Life and Times of Scrooge McDuck Companion* (2006): 195.

I've been puzzled by this ever since I first read the story in 2006. Each time I've re-read it, I've been unable to "get it". He seems to be making a reference to some previous meeting between him and the zombie which never takes place... What am I missing?

Comment: There is another earlier comic on the scrooge series I believe where Bombie the Zombie is introduced. I think I got the Dutch version laying around, but it would be quite a search. I actually read this comic you are refering to first as well and was confused too, untill I later on read the origin of the story.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid As in, present-day non-dreaming reality? That Don Rosa adventure must've passed me by!

Comment: That's a very, very click-baity title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Donald previously encountered Bombie in the story *[Voodoo Hoodoo](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=W%20OS%20%20238-02)*, published in *[Four Color #238](https://www.comics.org/issue/7373/)*  (September 1949). Needless to say, it wasn't a wholly pleasant experience.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Odd use of the word dreamboat in the first panel.

Comment: I think there is still an earlier story involving scrooge visiting a which doctor which triggers a series of events, one of them is Bombie the Zombie pursuing Scrooge, but he finds Donald instead because it takes tens of years for Bombie to reach Duck City.

Comment: According to [this wiki page](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Bombie_the_Zombie), this was Bombie's first appearance, and his first encounter with Donald Duck (hence Donald not recognising him). However, in the same issue, Scrooge explained that he'd incurred the wrath of a witch doctor 70 years earlier, and that Bombie had been stalking him ever since. Bombie was supposed to give the doll to Scrooge, but mistakenly gave it to Donald because he resembled a much younger Scrooge, and Bombie wasn't cognisant enough to take into account how much Scrooge's appearance would've changed with age.

Comment: In _[The Empire-Builder from Calisota](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire-Builder_from_Calisota)_ (published within _[The Life and Times of Scrooge McDuck](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Times_of_Scrooge_McDuck)_ in 1994), we were shown Bombie's backstory in much more detail, but it just expanded on the explanation Scrooge gave in _Voodoo Hoodoo_. A ten-year-old Donald made a brief appearance near the end of the story, but he and Bombie didn't meet until _Voodoo Hoodoo_.

Comment: @LogicDictates ah, that explains it! I remembered it as a separate story.

Comment: @user14111 , it's just comic sarcasm

Comment: what does **pizened** mean in the last panel ?

Comment: @Fattie - Pretty sure that's a mispronunciation of "poisoned".

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - You were probably thinking of _[The Empire-Builder from Calisota](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire-Builder_from_Calisota)_, where Bombie's backstory was retold in expanded form as a separate tale. But although Donald made a brief appearance as a ten-year-old in that story, he and Bombie did not meet.

Comment: @LogicDictates - DOH - thank you so much.  Cheers